# Get Spreadsheet cell calling a custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to get the A1 Notation of a Cell calling a Custom Function.

I found this but this is for active cell. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54414/in-google-script-get-the-spreadsheet-cell-calling-a-custom-function

Essentially if I want Cell A5 to Call `=TEST()`. I want the function to return the text value A5.

I want to use this as a cache identifier for an API Call.

Comment: Have you tested it? It'll work fine.

Answer (score 13):

There are subtle differences in different range returning method names- `active`,`current`,`selection`:

> [The term "active range" refers to **the** range that a user has selected in the active sheet, but **in a custom function it refers to the cell being "active"ly recalculated.**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveRange())
>
> [The current cell is **the** cell that has focus in the Google Sheets UI, and is highlighted by a dark border.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell())
>
> [A selection is **the set** of cells the user has highlighted in the sheet, which can be **non-adjacent** ranges. One cell in the selection is the current cell, where the user's current focus is.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

The first two are still range objects,while the latter is not. To reiterate, `getActiveRange()`

> **in a custom function it refers to the cell being "active"ly recalculated.**

---

> I want the function to return the text value A5.

Without Custom Functions,We can use:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

With Custom function,We can use:

```
function test() { 
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation(); 
}
```

Comment: I think I'm a little stuck on the fact of the "ActiveRange". As this cell may need to be reaclculated on loading the document that cause the cell not to be actively selected by the user. Can a Cell be active without it being selected? Is it marked as active while being calculated?

Comment: @jef29 Test and see for yourself.

Comment: "The term "active range" refers to the range that a user has selected in the active sheet, but in a custom function it refers to the cell being actively recalculated." — https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getactiverange