# Google Sheets App Script - Custom Function to find RichText (Bold/Italic) locations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I'm currently working on a project that's using Google Sheets to keep track of/maintain some translations of text (effectively some meta-data and then 2 columns for the original text and the translation).

The final application has some word-wrapping constraints and a variable-width font, so I created a custom function in app script to apply line breaks in order to facilitate visualizing how it would look.

```
function preview(text)
{
  if(text.startsWith('=')) // Copy of something else, so we don't care
    return text;

  text = text.trimEnd();
  text = text.replace("<4A>", "\n\n"); // For the sake of the preview, just treat <4A> as a new box
  text = text.replace(/\<&[a-zA-Z0-9]+\>/g,"────────"); // Assume the longest length (8 * 8)
  text = text.replace(/<\*.>/g,""); // Get rid of exit codes
  text = text.replace(/<S.+?>/g,""); // Get rid of special effects
  
  var output = "";
  var boxes = text.split("\n\n"); // Double newline is a forced new text box
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
  { // For each intentional text box
    var box = boxes[i];
    box = box.replace("<4E>","\n"); // Will technically forcibly always draw on the second line
    
    var lines = box.split('\n');
    var newboxFlag = false; // Flag to indicate if we draw a new line or new box

    for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++)
    { // For each intentional line in this box
      words = lines[j].split(' ');
      var word = "";    
      var currentLineLen = 0;
      for(var k = 0; k < words.length; k++)
      {
        word += words[k];
        
        var wordWidth = 0;
        for (var l = 0; l < word.length; l++)
        {
          var char = word.charAt(l);
          wordWidth += getCharacterWidth(char);
        }

        if(wordWidth + currentLineLen > 0x89)
        { // This word won't fit on this line, so it goes to a new line
          
          // Strip the first space, and just assume we don't have a string longer than 136 characters
          word = word.substr(1);
          wordWidth -= getCharacterWidth(' ');
          
          // Add a new line and flip the newboxFlag
          output += '\n';
          if(newboxFlag) output += '\n';
          newboxFlag ^= 1;
          currentLineLen = 0;
        }
        
        currentLineLen += wordWidth
        output += word;
        word = " ";
      }
      
      if (j != lines.length - 1)
      {
        output += '\n';  // line length is reset at the top
        if(newboxFlag) output += '\n';
        newboxFlag ^= 1;
      }
    }
    if(i != boxes.length - 1) output += '\n\n'; // If we're not on the last box, add the double new line
  }
  return output;
}
```

and I call it with `=preview(<CELL>)` (getCharacterWidth just pulls an integer from a character <-> width mapping).

This function works fine with raw text that does not contain any bold or italic characters.

The problem is, bold and italic characters often take more space than their normal counterparts, and in some cases will cause the previewed output text to incorrectly omit newlines where there should be some.

For example, the original text would be:

> This is *italic*. This is **bold**. This is ***bold and italic***.

=preview(text) ***should*** ideally be something like:

> This is *italic*.

> This is **bold**.

> This is ***bold***

> ***and italic***.

but instead, it might end up being like this:

> This is italic.

> This is bold. This

> is bold and italic.

Since the additional width of the bold/italic characters is not being accounted for, the function believes it has enough space to fit another word on the line.

It's OK if I can't output it, but I at least need to be able to identify what text is bold or italic. In Google Sheets, how can I write a custom function that is aware of RichText?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike I've added a sample. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried getRichText on the active range? Could you show the full `preview` function?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw it, I could understand about `This is italic.` and `This is bold.`. But I cannot understand the logic for retrieving `This is bold` and `and italic.`. Can I ask you about the detail information of it?

Comment: @TheMaster No I have not, I'm not sure how exactly that's doable... I could show you the full preview function, but it's really nothing beyond some javascript text processing.

I literally had it return 'typeof(text)' to verify it was seeing it as a string, I'm not sure how exactly to get the active range.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not sure I follow your question... I'll add some screenshots and try posting a code snippet, but I'm not really sure what other information to add.

Comment: @Tanaike Looks like I cannot add images yet. All of the text is simply passed as an argument to the function. If the translated text is in 'A1' then all I'm doing is having a cell with =preview(A1) which will manipulate the contents accordingly. It just so happens that as a result, 'text' does not give me any methods to handle RichText, it is just a string.

Comment: @TheMaster it looks like I may be able to do this if I pass the cell as a string instead, and then use getRichText() on it, so I'll try with that and post it as an answer if that's what it comes down to.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand the logic for retrieving the separated `This is bold` and `and italic`.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()` will return the active range. And yes, please post your JavaScript code.

Comment: @Tanaike It's not clear to me either, but I think, OP just wants the "displayed" width. Bold characters take up more  width. ``This is bold`` reaches the predetermined width before ``and italic``. I'm just guessing though

Comment: @TheMaster Your assertion is correct. I've added my code, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: @TheMaster Actually, your comment seems like enough for me to figure it out. 

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(str).getRichTextValue(); gives me the info I need and I can iterate over this.

Comment: @variantxyz Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311286 And If you  have a answer, consider posting it in the answerbox below.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. I noticed that the OP's issue had been resolved. Unfortunately, even when I saw it, I cannot still understand the logic for separating `This is bold` and `and italic.`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to TheMaster's comments, I was able to create a solution by changing my function to the following:

```
function preview(startcol, startrow)
{
  var str = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol) + startrow;
  var richtext = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(str).getRichTextValue();
  var runs = richtext.getRuns();
...
```

and setting my call to

```
=preview(COLUMN(<CELL>), ROW(<CELL>))
```

By looping over the runs accounting for getTextStyle().IsBold() or .IsItalic(), I can account for the RichText attributes.

```
if(runs[i].getTextStyle().IsBold() && runs[i].getTextStyle().IsItalic())
{
  wordWidth += getCharacterWidthBoldItalic(char);
}
else if(runs[i].getTextStyle().IsBold())
{
  wordWidth += getCharacterWidthBold(char);
}
else if(runs[i].getTextStyle().IsItalic())
{
  wordWidth += getCharacterWidthItalic(char);
}
else
{
  wordWidth += getCharacterWidth(char);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the logic for what you do when you encounter these boldgitalic types?

Comment: @TheMaster Sure, though it's just an if-else block where I check if both IsBold and IsItalic are active at the same time and use the character width accordingly.