# Extract Bold word in text from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can anyone know how to solve my Google Sheet Problem? I have a cell with a text, some word in text are bold, i want to extract only bold words from text, how can i do that?

Text in Cell:

I want to **register** for a **course**?

Expected Output:

register, course

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets App Script - Custom Function to find RichText (Bold/Italic) locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408312/google-sheets-app-script-custom-function-to-find-richtext-bold-italic-locati)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600172

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) class of a range, then you want to get the "runs" and verify if they are bold by using the [TextStyle.isBold()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#isbold) method.

### Example:

In a bound script to a sheet which contains the value "I want to **register** for a **course**?" in cell `A1` run the following function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  let runs = sheet.getRange('A1').getRichTextValue().getRuns()
  let boldWords = []
  runs.forEach((run)=>{
    if(run.getTextStyle().isBold()){
      boldWords.push(run.getText())
      
    }
    
  })
  console.log(boldWords.join(','))
}
// Output: register,course
```

Comment: How is it possible to paste the result into another cell? The result from A1 to B1, A2 to B2, and so on.