# get value from Range in Custom function returns "#ERROR!" during Loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a spreedsheet where I want to have a unique id for the row, I use the `Utilities` method `getUuid`.

I don´t want it to get the `Utilities.getUuid()` method when insertion of a row happens, so I want to get the value from the cell where the insertion has been made and check if it's empty then generate a new uuid if not, do nothing.

```
function uuid() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
 
  const val = activeRange.getValue();
  Logger.log(val)  

  if(!val) {
    return Utilities.getUuid();
  }
}
```

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Spreadsheet with values at least 2 rows and 2 cols
2. col #2 has the `=uuid(true)` in order to calculate the uuid

What is the expected output?

1. After the insertion  of a row in between the two rows, the row below should not change the uuid
2. The logger of the `val` should retrieve the value but it shows `#ERROR!`

Comment: It only says #ERROR! in the cell and in the logs
can check the spreadsheet and the scripts
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjTL5N7FnawT4IP9v321wFRY9C_DfFye20WSWBE3xFQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [Edit] to show at which step do you insert a row and whether above or below.

Comment: @OlegValter Although the documentation states  "must return a value", I find that not to be the case. If you don't return anything, no error is thrown.

Comment: @danielarias Better way is just to let go of custom functions and use something better like triggers, menu or buttons. Also look into developermetadata

Comment: You say  `I have a spreedsheet where I want to have a unique id for the row, I use the Utilities method getUuid.` documentation says `This identifier is not guaranteed to be unique across all time and space. As such, do not use in situations where guaranteed uniqueness is required.` so perhaps you should try another approach.

Comment: @Cooper  I did some research on this recently(Googling:)). Although the documentation does state that, it links a java class method: which says : `Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.`.  It's Crypto secure type4 uuid. So I don't think OP has to worry much.  Furthermore, Where else do you get a crypto secure ID in GAS?

Comment: @TheMaster one could also maintain a pool of already generated IDs (which I usually do) to avoid these rare collisions (I don't think the probability is any high enough to cause the lookup to short-circuit, and when lookups start to measure in millions of ids, one would want to find a better solution anyway)

Comment: @Aerials The active range cannot be multiple cells in a custom function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311286

Comment: Yes, so it seems more like a circular reference error. Asking the formula to read a previous value it created itself