# How to get a range from cell parameters without using strings in a custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm new to google sheet script and I'm trying to make a function that outputs the max value of possible opions from a DropDown list.

The feature of the function work but only when I call the following function in a cell

```
=MAXDROPDOWN(CELL("address";C13))
```

and it outputs an Error when doing

```
=MAXDROPDOWN(C13)
```

Where C13 is a dropdown list

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I'm really unable to I tried a lot of options but it never works.

=MAXDROPDOWN("C13") works but it disables all smart features associated with functions and cell reference since its a string provided so it loses its advantage of using it over my proposition above with =MAXDROPDOWN(CELL("address";C13))

I tried with getA1notation before to but I only saw it functioning on current active cells the function is called from and not on cells as parameters to the function

Thanks in advance for your help

```
function MAXDROPDOWN(cell1){
try {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell1);
var rule = cell.getDataValidation();
if (rule != null) {
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  return Math.max(...args[0])
} 
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}
```

Thank to TheWizEd I was able to do what I wanted. Below is what I did.

```
function MAXDROPDOWN(cell){
try {
var cell1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(CELL_ADDRESS(cell));
var rule = cell1.getDataValidation();
if (rule != null) {
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  return Math.max(...args[0])
} 
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}

function CELL_ADDRESS(cell) {
  let test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getFormula();
  let address = test.match(/\(.+\)/)[0];
  return(address.slice(1,-1));
}
```

Comment: Another way is `=MAXDROPDOWN("C13")`. Also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312131/

Comment: Hello TheMaster, thanks for answering, Yes =MAXDROPDOWN("C13") work but it disables all smart features associated with functions and cell reference so it loses its advantage of using it over my proposition above with =MAXDROPDOWN(CELL("address";C13)) 

I tried with getA1notation before to but I only saw it functioning on current active cells the function is called from and not on cells as parameters to the function. I Think I'm just missing a very small part to make it work for the cell in parameter but haven't figured out how yet

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to add answers. Add an another answer if you want to add something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `=MAXDROPDOWN(C13)` will pass the value of cell C13, not the address.  If you want the address you can parse the formula as shown in this example.

If I place this formula in any cell as `=MAXDROPDOWN(A1)` it will give me as address the string "A1"

```
function MAXDROPDOWN(cell) {
  let test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getFormula();
  let address = test.match(/\(.+\)/)[0];
  console.log(address.slice(1,-1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I was able to make it function like I wanted . I added an addtional function for other uses